# Merging two dataframes of different length

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

DataFrame 1:

```
        key A
   0    K0  AT
   1    K0  AT
   2    K0  AT
   3    K0  AT
```

DataFrame 2:

```
        key
   0    K0
```

I want to create a 3rd dataframe that gives me as a result:

```
        key  A
   0    K0  AT
```

The values in column 'A' are always the same for every key. I used every possible join or merge function, but it keeps giving me this result:

I want to get back a dataframe with numbers of row equal to the second dataframe (=1) and not equal to the first one (=4).

Anyone an idea? I've been trying for hours already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After merging, you can drop duplicates:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

I join this very usefull and complete documentation on concat join and merge : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/merging.html

Comment: been staring at it for hours, but the trick was in removing the duplicates